# AndEngine Touch ThreadPool error

Tags: java, android, andengine

I used and Engine in my project and I got the error below, I used the `OnAreaTouch` event on multiple sprites.

```
VERBOSE/AndEngine(1685):org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 0 item not yet recycled.Allocated 1 more.
```

Comment: Does it affect your game in any way? This usually happens when you press on that area multiple times, very fast.

Comment: Is any solution for this error.....

Comment: no, i touch only once and getting this message in my log - cat once untill i restart my application or change the level

Comment: This is not an error, it's basically how pools work. First time you want to get something from a pool, it needs to allocate before recycling..

Comment: so what i do for recycling The Touch Pool/AndEngine manually?

Comment: this is automatically done for you when necessary inside the reset and onUpdate methods of the PoolUpdateHandler class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person above Michael-F Portzert got it right in the comments. That's not an error, just a message. Andengine makes a Pool of update handlers with an initial size of 0. When one new is requested, it give a message that it had to make a new one.

If you created a condition that was somehow causing your items not to recycle back into the pool, you would see this message over and over until you ran out of memory.

Under normal circumstances Andengine will recycle these items to be resued next time a TouchEventRunnablePoolItem is needed. You do not need to do anything special other than making sure you are not keeping any references to the Pool item. You're not likely to be doing that.